# Loading own train data and labels in dataloader using pytorch?

Tags: python, dataset, preprocessing, pytorch

I have x_data and labels separately. How can I combine and load them in the model using `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`?

I have a dataset that I created and the training data has 20k samples and the labels are also separate. Lets say I want to load a dataset in the model, shuffle each time and use the batch size that I prefer. The Dataloader function does that. How can I combine and put them in the function so that I can train it in the model in pytorch?

Comment: See discussion on StackOverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924453/pytorch-how-to-use-dataloaders-for-custom-datasets

Comment: I found this example using TensorDataset to be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55588201/pytorch-transforms-on-tensordataset If `x_data` and `labels` are both Pytorch tensors, you can combine them into a `TensorDataset` then create a dataloader from that TensorDataset.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming both of `x_data` and `labels` are lists or numpy arrays,

```
train_data = []
for i in range(len(x_data)):
   train_data.append([x_data[i], labels[i]])

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=100)
i1, l1 = next(iter(trainloader))
print(i1.shape)
```

Comment: I end up getting errors saying that train_data is an np.object rather than a tensor.

Comment: For me, it worked. You can even use a shorter version: 
`trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader([ [x_data[i], labels[i]] for i in range(len(labels))], shuffle=True, batch_size=100)`. Thank you @ASHu2

Answer (score 7):

I think the standard way is to create a `Dataset` class object from the arrays and pass the `Dataset` object to the `DataLoader`.

One solution is to inherit from the Dataset class and define a custom class that implements `__len__()` and `__get__()`, where you pass `X` and `y` to the `__init__(self,X,y)`.

For your simple case with two arrays and without the necessity for a special `__get__()` function beyond taking the values in row `i`, you can also use transform the arrays into `Tensor` objects and pass them to `TensorDataset`.

Run the following code for a self-contained example.

```
# Create a dataset like the one you describe
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X,y = make_classification()

# Load necessary Pytorch packages
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset
from torch import Tensor

# Create dataset from several tensors with matching first dimension
# Samples will be drawn from the first dimension (rows)
dataset = TensorDataset( Tensor(X), Tensor(y) )

# Create a data loader from the dataset
# Type of sampling and batch size are specified at this step
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size= 3)

# Quick test
next(iter(loader))
```